# Where is rc.local in Debian 9 (Debian Stretch)

Tags: debian

It seems there is no `/etc/rc.local` in the latest stable version of Debian, **Debian Stretch**. Where is it? Is /etc/rc.local obsolete?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`rc.local` is being deprecated.

It seems you can still have one though:

```
cat <<EOF >/etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0
EOF
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start rc-local
systemctl status rc-local
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Wed 2017-06-28 11:32:36 UTC; 3min 13s ago
```

The vendor preset should be enabled. You can add some `echo 123 >/proof` to your rc.local and reboot, making sure it works - I confirm it does, using the last Debian Stretch AMI on EC2, ...

Comment: it's actually a big mistake deprecating such a proven parts of the system like rc.local! If you move to another things like systemd - OK, just *don't use* the old part for it, but why removing it?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `/etc/rc.local` is invoked from `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, the latter file belonging to [initscripts](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/initscripts) package. At least if you have _SysV init_ installed.

Comment: Being deprecated in favor of what?

Comment: it's not working, as you need to add magical extra service `rc-local.service` to invoke the `/etc/rc.local`. It's not working if i need something bigger then `echo hello world` - packages installation, db config, modules config.

Comment: [`/etc/rc.local` was superseded in 1983.](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/rc.local-is-history.html)  It might be time to get used to that.  (-:

Answer (score 1):

/etc/rc.local is not invoked from /etc/init.d/rc.local (at least on the Debian stretch system I've just installed today), because /etc/init.d/rc.local does not exist in that system.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer

Comment: explanation is above, you probably don't got the sys5 compat scripts which that is part of. (we can have our opinions about whether some upstream devs should even be allowed to deprecate something we want to use, but hey)